# Interpolating a dataframe with x columns into <x columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to reduce a 6 columns x 2 rows dataframe into, for example, a 3 columns x 2 rows dataframe, based on pre-calculated bins.

I have a dataframe that looks like this, for example:

```
df =
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6 etc
0  3  4  5  2  4  1  2 etc
1  5  1  3  5  2  2  3 etc
```

and a list of lists that looks like this:

```
dir = [[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

This list of lists represents the column headers.

I want to loop through the rows in my dataframe and interpolate new values based on the length of each list. Basically just take a mean value based on the column headers. For example, the [0,1,2] list contains 3,4,5 values, therefore the new value should be (3+4+5)/3 = 4.

The new dataframe should look like this:

```
df1 =
    0   1   2
0   4   3   1.5  
1   3   3.5 2.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create helper dictionary, `rename` columns and use `mean` for aggregate by new columns names:

```
L = [[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
d = {k: i for i, x in enumerate(L) for k in x}
print (d)
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2}

df = df.rename(columns=d).mean(axis=1, level=0)
print (df)
     0    1    2
0  4.0  3.0  1.5
1  3.0  3.5  2.5
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.rename(columns=d))
   0  0  0  1  1  2  2
0  3  4  5  2  4  1  2
1  5  1  3  5  2  2  3
```